# How to resolve 'dataSource' required argument error in Syncfusion Flutter chart?

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, syncfusion

I'm working on a Flutter project utilizing the Syncfusion Flutter Charts package to implement an Exponential Moving Average (EMA) indicator. While attempting to configure the chart with my dataset, I encountered an error stating a named parameter 'dataSource' is required but not provided.

**Background:** An EMA indicator is calculated by adding the closing price for a number of time periods and dividing the total by the number of periods. My goal is to visualize financial data using Syncfusion's `HiloOpenCloseSeries` along with `EmaIndicator` for trend analysis.

**Issue:** Upon compiling, Flutter throws the following error: "The named parameter 'dataSource' is required, but there's no corresponding argument." This occurs despite my understanding that `dataSource` should be defined within the `HiloOpenCloseSeries` or within the `EmaIndicator`'s configuration.

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- Checked Syncfusion documentation for examples of `EmaIndicator` usage but found limited information on required parameters.
- Reviewed similar issues on Stack Overflow and GitHub, but none specifically address missing 'dataSource' in the context of `EmaIndicator`.

**Question:** How can I correctly provide the 'dataSource' argument for the `EmaIndicator` in a Syncfusion Flutter chart? Are there specific configurations or properties I'm overlooking?

#### Code Snippets

```dart
// Relevant imports
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

// Simplified Widget demonstrating the issue
class EMAChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EMAChartState createState() => _EMAChartState();
}

class _EMAChartState extends State<EMAChart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SfCartesianChart(
        series: <ChartSeries>[
          HiloOpenCloseSeries<ChartData, DateTime>(
            dataSource: _getChartData(), // Simplified data source for illustration
            xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
            // Other necessary mappings...
          )
        ],
        indicators: <TechnicalIndicators<ChartData, DateTime>>[
          EmaIndicator<ChartData, DateTime>(
            seriesName: 'HiloOpenClose',
            valueField: 'high',
            // Missing dataSource argument highlighted here
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Dummy data generator for illustration
  List<ChartData> _getChartData() {
    return [/* Your chart data here */];
  }
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.high);
  final DateTime x;
  final double high;
}
```

**Note:** For simplicity, I've only included essential parts of the code demonstrating the issue with 'dataSource'.

Comment: You need to provide the dataSource attribute when initializing a ChartSeries. See an example here: https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/SfCartesianChart-class.html

Comment: Hello, @jraufeisen I updated my data, can you help me to clue these two pieces of code to integrate the EMA to my bar chart with the data, please? Thanks for any help you can provide.